# CardView is not inflating properly using LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview, layout-inflater

I want to add CardView programmatically.

**Here is my Main Activity XML Layout (activity_main.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my CardViewTemplate (card_view_template.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewTemplate"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This is a Card" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Here is my Java Code (MainActivity.java)**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_template, parent);
```

[image: See Output]

Everything works fine till here.

Now I want to add Card at certain position in my **activity_main.xml** as I am using multiple CardViews, I want to add Cards at certain position. Hence, instead of the above code, I tried this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_template, null);
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
parent.addView(view, 0);
```

But it does not inflate properly. Only the Text is visible, The Card does not seem to appear. [image: See Output Here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dynamically adding views, we shouldn't inflate the `View` with null `ViewGroup` parent.

In this `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_template, null);` here parent is specified as null, this caused the problem.

Specify the parent to which the `View` will be attached to and only set attach to parent as `false`. This way Parent will be specified but not attached.

Hence first declare parent (root) and then create `View` and specify the parent (root) and set attach to parent (root) `false`

This is the correct statement
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_template, parent, false);`

Hence the complete code will be:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_template, parent, false);
parent.addView(view, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that you use directly the linear layout ,like:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_template, null);
LinearLayout LL = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
LL.addView(view,0);
```

Comment: this is the exact same code as the question but you renamed parent to LL

Comment: @karounka pedro kilombo, Not working, still the same problem. The Card is not appearing. Only the text is appearing. as shown in the output screenshot: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEq4A.jpg"